# How to create gridview updating event dynamically?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview

```
public partial class Gridvw_expt2 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    SqlCommand com;
    SqlDataAdapter da;
    DataSet ds;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["gj"].ConnectionString);
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {          
        com = new SqlCommand("Select * from tblExpt",con);
        da = new SqlDataAdapter(com);
        ds = new DataSet();
        da.Fill(ds);
        if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0] != null)
        {
            GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;

            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();

            GridView1.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(abc);
            GridView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "id" };
            GridView1.RowEditing += new GridViewEditEventHandler(bc);
        }    
        else
            Response.Write("fkj");
    }

    protected void abc(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(e.RowIndex);
    }
    protected void bc(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)sender;
        gv.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    }
}
```

the row used to get in edit mode only if i edit the next row means first row never get in edited mode.Please help why so.

Comment: What is the exact compiler message?

Comment: The GridView 'GridView1' fired event RowEditing which wasn't handled

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Istead of

```
GridView1.Attributes.Add("onrowupdating", "abc");
```

do this:

```
GridView1.RowUpdating += new GridViewUpdateEventHandler(abc);
```

---

Also, Instead of

```
GridView1.Attributes.Add("DataKeyNames", "id");
```

do this

```
GridView1.DataKeyNames = new string[] { "id" };
```

---

Also x 2, Instead of

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0].ToString() != null)
```

do this

```
if (ds.Tables[0].Rows[0] != null) //.ToString() will cause an exception if it is actuall null
```

---

Why do I feel like I am teaching a class :)

Comment: Thanks a lot but the same exception is still there

Comment: well your approach is not ideal.. you should connect the event handler from the aspx file.. the exception is probably due to incorrect postback handling.. I would recommend looking up a book.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you haven't set up a handler to handle [GridView.RowEditing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowediting.aspx).  On your gridview (in the .aspx) you need to wire up a method which will deal with RowEditing.

You're gridview code will look like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
</asp:GridView>
```

You need to add:

```
OnRowEditing="nameOfMethodYouWantToFire"
```

so it looks like:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowEditing="nameOfMethodYouWantToFire">
</asp:GridView>
```

Where `nameOfMethodYouWantToFire` is in your code behind (your C#) and it handles the event. Something like this:

```
protected void nameOfMethodYouWantToFire(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
  {
    //Your code here
  }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for  reply and thanks in advance for further replies   How editing  to be done if is case for code behind or say dynamically?

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean.  This will work wether the GridView has been populated dynamically or not